rdflib 7.1.1 namespace bindings not being serialized in turtle file
I am trying to export a knowledge graph as a turtle file, but for some reason my prefixes don't seem to make it into the turtle file (or at least not all of them).
Minimum reproducable code (written in a jupyter notebook, with rdflib 7.1.1):
from rdflib import URIRef, Graph, Literal
import itertools

def make_example_IRI(ID_list):
    return URIRef("http://example.org/" + 
                    '/'.join([str(id).lower()
                        for id in ID_list])
                    )

tg = Graph()

tbls = ['A', 'B',]
cols = ['X', 'Y',]
rows = ['i', 'j', 'k']
data = [1,2,3]

label_iri = URIRef('http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label')

for combo in itertools.product(tbls, rows, cols, data):
    row_iri = make_example_IRI([combo[0], 'row', combo[1]])
    col_iri = make_example_IRI([combo[0], 'col', combo[2]])
    datum = Literal(combo[-1])
    tg.add((row_iri, col_iri, datum))
    tg.add((col_iri, label_iri, Literal(combo[2])))

bind_list = []   
for tab in tbls:
    nsR = (f'tab{tab}', make_example_IRI([tab, 'row', '/']))
    nsC = (f'tab{tab}_col', make_example_IRI([tab, 'col', '/']))
    bind_list.append(nsR)
    bind_list.append(nsC)

for short, long in bind_list:
    tg.bind(short, long, override=True, replace=True)

If I use the following to print my namespaces, the newly bound ones show up with a long list of default namespaces.
[n for n in tg.namespaces()]

my namespaces look like:
[ ... 
 ('tabA', rdflib.term.URIRef('http://example.org/a/row//')),
 ('tabA_col', rdflib.term.URIRef('http://example.org/a/col//')),
 ('tabB', rdflib.term.URIRef('http://example.org/b/row//')),
 ('tabB_col', rdflib.term.URIRef('http://example.org/b/col//')),
 ('tabC', rdflib.term.URIRef('http://example.org/c/row//')),
 ('tabC_col', rdflib.term.URIRef('http://example.org/c/col//'))]

but then running:
tg.serialize(format="turtle", destination="tg.ttl")

gives a turtle with the following prefixes:
@prefix ns1: <http://example.org/b/col/> .
@prefix ns2: <http://example.org/a/col/> .
@prefix ns3: <http://example.org/c/col/> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .

so not only does it ignore the shortened prefixes I tried to bind, but it completely ignores that the "row" related items should also have prefixes.
The rest of the .ttl looks something like:
ns2:x rdfs:label "X" .

ns2:y rdfs:label "Y" .

ns2:z rdfs:label "Z" .

<http://example.org/a/row/i> ns2:x 1,
        2,
        3 ;
    ns2:y 1,
        2,
        3 ;
    ns2:z 1,
        2,
        3 .

When I would expect
tabA:1 tabA_col:x 1,
                  2,
                  3 ;
...

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug?
